# Positioning a toast to top

Tags: android, native, toast

The inflating a custom toast it is not positioned on the top like the system toast using Toast.makeToast(). Is it possible to position the custom inflated toast to the same place as the system toast?

[system toast using Toast.makeText()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT3Rv.png)

[custom toast by inflating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om8uj.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toastLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00000000"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toastTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I think the problem is using cardElevation the higher the value the lower it appear on the scree. Any idea to overcome this problem?

Comment: \\ if my answer works .. please mark it as accepted answer .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sample Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0, 0)
 .show();
```